# Amazon ec2 wordpress file upload max size

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-ec2

So basically I have my wordpress site on Amazon EC2, the max file size to upload is only 1M. 
How can I change it? 
I've tried many different ways like modifing php.ini, wp-config.php, etc. with httpd restart
But none of them work.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can controlled it by php.ini, but it can be overridden in the site configuration. Once you make the change then you have to restart apache server for changes to take effect.

Comment: I did modify the php.ini in the wordpress folder, wp-admin folder, and etc folder.